# Compile KLEE on MIPS error

Tags: llvm, mips, klee

Now I want to use KLEE on MIPS. but when I compile it by makefile, there is a `error:unknown target triple "mips64el-unkown-linux-gnu", please use -triple or -arch`
I don not know whether KLEE surport MIPS, and KLEE's documents also have this informations, Did anyone use KLEE on MIPS?

Comment: you'd better ask on klee's mail list, klee-dev@imperial.ac.uk

Comment: Did you mean to say `mips64el-unknown-linux-gnu`?

Answer (score 0):

I have use the LLVM-2.9, it not support mispel-64 well,

When compile the KLEE, it found the LLVM can not recognize the architecture, so it will report this error